# confused in a simple Producer-Consumer implement with synchronized, wait, notifyAll

Tags: java, wait, synchronized, notify

in my code, I tried two similar condition codes in while loop to check the boxes is full when the producer thread needs to wait in producer code. but it's output is different, I am confused.

the error is when I use a variable named 'size' to save the value of boxes's size in thread's run code. in some cases, the program will be blocking like death.

Producer code:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable{
    private final List<String> boxes;
    private final int MAX_SIZE = 5;
    public Producer(List<String> aboxes) {
        super();
        this.boxes = aboxes;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            synchronized (boxes) {
                try {
                    int size = boxes.size(); // OR int size = this.boxes.size();

                    // while(MAX_SIZE == this.boxes.size()) {      OK
                    // while(MAX_SIZE == boxes.size()) {           OK
                    while (MAX_SIZE == size) {                  // ERROR
                        boxes.wait();
                    }

                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    String product = "product :  " + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
                    boxes.add(product);

                    boxes.notifyAll();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note on Java naming conventions: Usually field names only use `ALL_CAPS` when they are constants, which in Java means `static final` (implicitly or explicitly), otherwise they use `camelCase`.

Answer (score 4):

The condition in while statement in your current case is static i.e. for `MAX_SIZE == size` value of both variable doesn't change when the while loop is evaluated again.

When `notify` is called on `boxes` and the producer thread is notified, the while loop is evaluated again. As both value have not changed, both will have value of `5` and when the loop is evaluated, it value will again be `5`. So while condition will be `5==5` resulting in `wait` being called again. i.e. Once it entered the `while` loop, the condition will always be `true`, resulting in the infinite blocking.

But with condition `MAX_SIZE == boxes.size()`, the value of `boxes.size()` is dynamic and it will be changed, I guess by consumer here. Let's say, consumer remove one element from this list so `boxes.size()=4` and it calls `notify` on `boxes`. So the producer thread is notified and the condition in `producer` becomes `5 == 4` which results in while condition being `false` and exit the loop. Hence the code execute as expected

Comment: Thanks, Ashishkumar Singh.I want to know more about what makes the condition static in the while statement `MAX_SIZE == size`? I think when the Producer thread is notified, the code in `run()` block is executed sequentially like the order of the code. the other words, I think the executing of each `run()` block may make the variable of `size` be reassignment.

Comment: No. It will execute from the point where it was halted and that will be wait method call here